# Getting error while creating a new Rule on an existing EventBus using CDK

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to add a new Rule on an existing EventBus using CDK. My intention is to publish the event to an existing SQS Queue. Below is how I am doing it.

```
private void CreateNewRuleOnExistingEventBus(IQueue queue)
{            
    var rule = new Rule(this, "MyNewRule", new RuleProps
    {
        RuleName = "MyNewRule",
        EventBus = new EventBus(this, "MyExistingEventBus", new EventBusProps
        {
            EventBusName = "MyExistingEventBus"
        }),
        Description = "New Rule on existing MyExistingEventBus",
        EventPattern = new EventPattern
        {
            Detail = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "Type", new[] {"MY_NEW_TYPE"} }
            }
        },
        Enabled = true
    });

    rule.AddTarget(new SqsQueue(queue));

    // ReSharper disable once ObjectCreationAsStatement
    new CfnOutput(this, ruleName, new CfnOutputProps
    {
        ExportName = ruleName,
        Value = rule.AttrArn
    });
}
```

I am getting the below error

```
Deployment failed: Error: Stack Deployments Failed: Error: The stack named ***** failed to deploy: UPDATE_ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Event bus MyExistingEventBus already exists. (Service: AWSEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceAlreadyExistsException; Request ID: b4605949-3677-4a86-8185-6bb0c8d20fae; Proxy: null)
    at deployStacks (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.16.0/x64/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:330:130558)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async CdkToolkit.deploy (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.16.0/x64/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:330:146782)
    at async exec4 (/opt/hostedtoolcache/node/18.16.0/x64/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/index.js:385:51296)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `new EventBus()` creates a new Event Bus.

You need [`EventBus.fromEventBusName()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_events.EventBus.html#static-fromwbreventwbrbuswbrnamescope-id-eventbusname):

```js
...
eventBus: EventBus.fromEventBusName(self, "eventBus", "MyExistingEventBus"),
...
```

This is TypeScript, but it would work the same in any CDK language.

This pattern applies to virtually all AWS resources and their corresponding CDK constructs - simply instantiating the construct will always attempt to create a new resource. To import a resource instead, look for `from*` methods in the construct class.